# How to average 3 values in Sql Server?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, average

I have three variables :-

```
@ScoreA DECIMAL(10,7)
@ScoreB DECIMAL(10,7)
@ScoreC DECIMAL(10,7)
@FinalScore DECIMAL(10, 7)
```

I wish to get the average of the three scores. BUT 1, 2 or all 3 values *might* be zero.

Eg. scenarios:

- A = 1.4, B=3.5, C=5.0; FinalScore = 3.3
- A = 0.0, B=0.0, C=0.0; FinalScore = 0.0
- A = 1.1, B=0.0, C=0.0; FinalScore = 1.1
- A = 0.0, B=2.0, C=4.8; FinalScore = 3.4

Cheers!

Comment: I assume you are ok with CTE(sql-server-2008 question) so I think using them is better choice here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF @A > 0 OR @B > 0 OR @C > 0
    SELECT ((@A + @B + @C) / 
        (0 + 
        CASE WHEN @A = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
        CASE WHEN @B = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
        CASE WHEN @C = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ))
ELSE
    SELECT 0.0
```

#### EDIT

Modified query to now handle *divide by zero* scenario's.

#### EDIT2

Here is "the trick with the AVG(..) function" :) with Common Table Expression

```
WITH T(I) AS (SELECT @A UNION SELECT @B UNION SELECT @C)
SELECT AVG(I) FROM T
WHERE I > 0
```

Comment: hmm. I never thought of that. I was thinking it would be some trick with the AVG(..) function... brb :)

Comment: Nice. works :) Not sure why u have => (0 + <case stuff> ) ... that 0 + is .. redundant???

Comment: Late, but Google led me here. Quick comment: The CTE should be UNION ALL, as UNION eliminates duplicate rows, which in this case would be equivalent to eliminating n-1 equal values. IOW, if @A = @B, then you are getting the average of @A and @C, not @A, @B and @C.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ((@A + @B + @C) / 
        (CASE WHEN (@A = 0.0 AND @B = 0.0 AND @C = 0.0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
        + CASE WHEN @A = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
        + CASE WHEN @B = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END  
        + CASE WHEN @C = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
        )
      )
```

Comment: Sure about that? doesn't A + B + C / 0 .. occur .. if all the data was zero? that would be a *divide by zero* .. ??

Comment: Yes. In that case it would divide by 1.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is easier to read and understand:

```
DECLARE
    @ScoreA DECIMAL(10,7),
    @ScoreB DECIMAL(10,7),
    @ScoreC DECIMAL(10,7),
    @FinalScore DECIMAL(10, 7)

SET @ScoreA = 1.4
SET @ScoreB = 3.5
SET @ScoreC = 5.0

DECLARE 
    @AVG TABLE (value DECIMAL(10,7))

INSERT INTO @AVG
    SELECT @ScoreA WHERE @ScoreA > 0
    UNION
    SELECT @ScoreB WHERE @ScoreB > 0
    UNION
    SELECT @ScoreC WHERE @ScoreC > 0

SELECT COALESCE(AVG(value), 0) FROM @AVG
```